# Fragments covering one another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to make an aplication which has a MainActivity and multiple fragments which I call from drawer and I want backbutton to work. And orientation change needs to work aswell.

The problem I have is that when I open a second fragmes it opens on top of current and I can see and click elements from the first.

The way I call fragments:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MainFragment();

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2
            fragment = new Fragment3();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        //my solution without backbutton
        /*if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1)
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();*/


        FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        //ft.hide(fragmentManager);
        ft.addToBackStack(MainFragment.class.getName());
        ft.commit();
```

And my back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else { //I create an alert  }
```

I am guessing there is a problem eather in the way I create fragments or in the fragment layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  `ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)` instead of `add`. This will replace the first fragment with the second.

Comment: The result is the same. But if I change the background of the fragment to white I dont see the other fragment anymore but I am not sure this is the best solution because now I can have 10 fragments that exist one ontop of the other.